# flyspell's highlight cleared after a "save word" action

Tags: flyspell

After running `flyspell-buffer`, all misspelled words are highlighted. However, after saving a word, all of the highlighting is gone. How can I avoid that? My `flyspell-persistent-highlight` is set `t`.

Comment: If you add a word to the dictionary and ispell (used by flyspell) thinks the word is now correctly spelled, how does ispell (used by flyspell) know to continue marking it as misspelled each time your cursor gets near that word (assuming that you have `flyspell-mode` enabled, that is)?

Comment: If you wish to break `flyspell-do-correct` you can comment out the `(fs-unhighlight-at cursor-location)` statements within said function.

Comment: @lawlist Its not about the added word, but all other misspelled words in the buffer.

Comment: I am wondering about this too. I have the same problem. After saving a word to the dictionary, I have to hit flyspell-buffer again.

Answer (score 0):

Via https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlySpell#toc9 and https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4oc7pg/spellcheck_flyspellmode_underlines_disappear_when/d5l9vtt/ I found this solution:

```
(defun flyspell-buffer-after-pdict-save (&rest _)
  (flyspell-buffer))

(advice-add 'ispell-pdict-save :after #'flyspell-buffer-after-pdict-save)
```

Unfortunately this seems to trigger a bit too often: `flyspell-buffer` now also runs after correcting a word or even after dismissing the `mouse-2` menu without any action.